# Deleting a Character in the String

Tags: c

i want to delete the character that user give it's number in the program but it deletes next one,it is because 0 is counted in my code how can i change the code that exactly deletes the number that user want?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char a[30];
    int n,i;
    printf("enter a string\n");
    gets(a);
    printf("enter position you want to delete\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=1;a[i];i++);
    strcpy(&a[n],&a[n+1]);
    printf("the result is:\n");
    puts(a);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you need to use indents!

Comment: Your source and destination of strcpy overlap. Also your for loop accomplishes nothing, and you're not checking the bounds of the input number from the user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is not valid, you cannot use `strcpy()` when source and destination buffers overlap.

You must use [`memmove()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memmove) for cases like those. Note that `memmove()` is not a string function so it doesn't use 0-termination, thus you need to pass the number of bytes to move.

Also, never use `gets()`, it's very dangerous (no protection against buffer overflow).

You should do something like:

```
char a[128];

if(fgets(a, sizeof a, stdin))
{
    const size_t len = strlen(a);
    int n;

    printf("enter index> ");
    flush(stdout);
    if(scanf(" %d", &n) == 1 && n < len)
    {
        memmove(a + n, a + n + 1, len - n);
    }
}
```

The above uses 0-based indexing. If you want 1-based indexing, replace the inner-most `if`:

```
if(scanf(" %d", &n) == 1 && n > 0 && n <= len)
{
    --n;
    memmove(a + n, a + n + 1, len - n));
}
```

Comment: But still, you didn't answer OP's doubt - you are moving string from a+n, so when someone wants to remove 1st character, you will "remove" 2nd.

Comment: what is the library for flash and memmove?

Comment: @s12b11 flash? The `memmove()` function is declared in `<string.h>`, it's part of the standard library.

Comment: If think `len - (n + 1)` should be `len - n` as one also needs to move the `0`-terminator.

Comment: @alk Doh! [Obi-Wan](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/O/obi-wan-error.html) strikes again. Fixed, thanks.